# gdb dump memory as specific type

Tags: gdb, coredump

I'm trying to debug a memory problem in my application.

I want to dump a memory region to a file as unsigned int

This is the print command of what I want to dump

`p/x *((unsigned int*)0x800@8`

Can I dump the memory to a file and keep it as unsigned int and not hex\binary?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I dump the memory to a file and keep it as unsigned int and not hex\binary?

It's hard to tell precisely what you want to achieve.

If you simply want to save the output from `p/x *((unsigned int*)0x800@8` in a file, you could do this:

```
(gdb) set logging on
(gdb) p/x *((unsigned int*)0x800@8
(gdb) set logging off
```